# Underline menu anchor animation with pseudo css

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

i'm having difficulties animating a menu item,

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nunoooo/Lc9gp8fb/8/)

What i need is that, when a user clicks the menu item the bar that appears on hover to switch side with an animation.

[image]

So far i have 2 bars with the following code, the **:after** starting were the **:before** ends, but i can't make the **:before** bar to finish were the **:after** start's on click (:active and :focus)

Does anyone has some idea how to do this? i try'ed jquery but with no success.

HTML:

```
         <a class="item" href="http://www.google.com" title=" competências" target="_blank">
                <span class="nav-item">Competências</span>
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="" title=" Industrias" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">Industrias</span>
            </a>
            <a href="" title=" Soluções" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">Soluções</span>
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="" title=" About" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">About</span>
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="" title=" Parceiros" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">Parceiros</span>
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="" title=" Pessoas" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">Pessoas</span>
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="" title=" Contactos" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">Contactos</span>
            </a>
            <span class="skew-bar"></span>
            <a class="item" href="" title=" Blog" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">Blog</span>
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="" title=" Notícias" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">Notícias</span>
            </a>
            <a class="item" href="" title=" Recursos" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">Recursos</span>
            </a>
            <span class="skew-bar"></span>
            <a class="item" href="" title=" English" target="">
                <span class="nav-item">EN</span>
            </a>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav a {
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*BEFORE ON HOVER*/
nav a span:before {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translateY(22px);
    width: 1px;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    content: '';
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1), opacity 0.1s linear 0.3s;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1), opacity 0.1s linear 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1), opacity 0.1s linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1), opacity 0.1s linear 0.3s;
}


nav a span:hover::before {
    width: 50%;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}


/*BEFORE ON CLICK FOCUS*/
nav a span:after {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-3px);
    width: 1px;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    content: '';
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1), opacity 0.1s linear 0.3s;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1), opacity 0.1s linear 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1), opacity 0.1s linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1), opacity 0.1s linear 0.3s;
}


nav a span:active::after,nav a span:focus::after {
    width: 50%;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus is in the `.item` not in the `span`, so your selector should be like

```
nav a:focus span::after
```

Here you have the code working https://jsfiddle.net/Lc9gp8fb/9/

**-- EDIT --**

With this update you can close `:before` to the right.

I set to `nav a span:before`

```
margin-right: 50%;
float: right;
```

To keep it in the middle, and when hover it I set

```
float: left;
```

So, when it is hovered it will have `float: left;` and the animation will be from left to right, and when it is not hovered the animation will be also from left to right because it will have `float: right;`

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc9gp8fb/15/

Comment: Awesome, this solve'd 80% of my problem i was targeting the class wrongly thank you, is there any way so that the :before bar does not go back, but forward? Cheers

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, very interesting use! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the :active state does not persist after click in pure css, you will need javascript to end the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Yo shold try to position absolutly the pseudoelements:

```
nav a {
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;

    position: relative
}

nav a span:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:abolute;
    top:100%;
    height:3px;
    background-color:#000000;

    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -moz-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -o-transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}
nav a span:before {
    left: 0%;
    right: 100%;
}
nav a:hover span:before {
    right: 50%;
}
nav a span:after {
    left: 100%;
    right: 0%;
}
nav a:active span:after {
    left: 50%;
}
```

This will make a 100% width line on clicking and 50% on hover. Is this waht you are looking for?

Comment: This does not work how i was looking for, but thank you